# Printing line number through -finstrument-functions option of gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there any way in `-finstrument-functions` option of gcc to get the line number of the current function such as `__LINE__` of gcc.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only access `__LINE__` at preprocessing time and `__cyg_profile` functions are inserted much later. What you could do is get return address (via `__builtin_return_address`) and symbolize it at runtime (e.g. by calling `addr2line`). This will of course only work if caller's code was compiled with debuginfo.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Tsyvarev below, `__builtin_return_address` isn't needed as `__cyg_profile` gets function address as parameter.

Comment: But mine is ARM architecture which does not support `__builtin_return_address(2)`

Comment: Hm but why `2`? You only need return address of caller, which is `__builtin_return_address(1)`.

Comment: Profile functions accept `this_fn` as a the first parameter, which is address of the function's start.  So `__builtin_return_address` is not needed at all.